# Est-ce qu'il faut répéter le pronom après « mes amis et moi » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

Est-ce qu'on dit :

> Mes amis et moi adorons cet artiste.

ou

> Mes amis et moi, nous adorons cet artiste.

Donc, est-ce qu'il faut répéter le pronom personnel après le *sujet complexe* (je ne connais pas le terme pour ce type de sujet, je l'ai inventé) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La répétition du sujet est possible, mais elle porte souvent une connotation naïve, enfantine ou populaire.

En politique, notamment, elle trahit l'intention démagogique de l'orateur, qui s'efforce de "*faire peuple*" sur la suggestion de ses conseillers en communication. Il dira donc volontiers:

> Le gouvernement, il fait son travail

au lieu de

> le gouvernement fait son travail

Il reste que la deuxième forme est de loin préférable sur le plan littéraire.

Le cas que vous soulevez est un peu plus complexe, car le sujet est une énumération de "co-sujets", si l'on peut dire. Dans ce cas, la reprise du "nous" prend une valeur synthétique qui la rend utile, donc acceptable, contrairement à l'exemple de sujet unique cité ci-dessus.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Il n'y a pas de différence dans le sens; la première forme parait plus élégante mais la seconde n'est ni gauche ni lourde; dans le cas précis de la question les deux formes sont utilisables sans risque de se voir reprocher des fautes de langage, graves ou anodines.  Cela est entendu pour d'autres cas de la première personne du pluriel avec des sujets à la complexité plus grande que celle du sujet de la question.

**2.** Pour la troisième personne du pluriel, assez bizarrement, l'effet de l'introduction d'un pronom personnel n'est plus le même et semble toujours gauche **sauf** dans des cas où le locuteur donne à son énonciation des connotations particulières telles qu'une emphase sur l'intégrité des personnes représentées par le sujet, une insistance sur le rôle de conclusion qu'a la phrase énoncée ou un ton de forte contradiction de ce qui a été dit précédemment,  et alors il prononce assez souvent le pronom et le verbe avec plus de force.

> - Les chiens et les chats, ils aiment la viande. (*et vous pouvez dire ce que vous voulez*)
> - Le premier service et celui de la comptabilité, ils ont fait leur travail; c'est à vous qu'incombe la responsabilité de cette faute. (*il n'y a pas de doute à avoir*)

Cette utilisation d'un pronom personnel « intrusif » est aussi valable pour la première personne du pluriel **et** pour des sujets « simples ».

> - L'équipe et moi, son capitaine, nous n'avons pas de comptes à vous rendre, adressez-vous à l'entraineur.
> - Le bus, il est arrivé à l'heure, c'est lui qui se cherche une excuse.

**3.**  Dans les cas de sujets « complexes » très longs il semble que pour la première personne du pluriel il soit préférable dans certains cas d'introduire le pronom, particulièrement lorsque le verbe a une forme simple.

> - Moi, mes amis habituels et tous ceux qui sont devenus nos amis pendant plus de six longs mois lors de ce périple inimaginable en bicyclette, nous allons en Chine l'année prochaine.